# move a mysql database row up or down with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and some php that allows you to create an entry in the database, update an entry, and view the entries as a web page or xml. What I want to do is add a function to move an entry in the database up or down by one row, or, send to the top of the database or bottom.

I've seen some online comments about doing this type of thing that suggested doing a dynamic sort when displaying the page, but I'm looking for a persistent resort. I've seen one approach suggested that would be to have a separate "sort" field in the database that is agnostic of the actual database sort key, but I'm not sure why that would be better than actually re-ordering the database

Here is a dump of the table structure:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `hlnManager`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `hln_stations`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hln_stations` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `station_title` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `station_display_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `station_subtitle` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `station_detailed_description` text NOT NULL,
  `stream_url_or_playlist_url` text NOT NULL,
  `link_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `small_thumbnail_graphic_url` text NOT NULL,
  `large_thumbnail_graphic_url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

Comment: You answered your own question - use a sort by field. The database keys are intended to be unique identifiers and overloading their meaning will cause you problems later on in the project.

Comment: What problems would changing the unique id cause me in the future?

Comment: @alphablender you would never be able to refer to a particular record with any sort of consistency, as conceivably every other field may become editable at some point since they are "public facing".

Comment: First thing that jumps into my head is that every time you exchange the PK in this table, you'll have to update any referring foreign keys that you have.

Comment: BTW, the proper way to do this is to actually have a second table that holds the ordering information. Why? You want to have a separation of concerns. 'hln_stations' seems to be holding important data about something. The ordering of that data has nothing to do with it, it has to do with how you want to display it (aka. view). (caveat: if the ordering is part of the hln_stations data and not just a relic of how you want it displayed, just ignore me ;0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Reordering" the database...  SQL Databases typically do not make any guarantees on what order (if any) they will return records in short of an ORDER BY clause.

1. You need a "SortOrder" type column.  I suggest you make it an int with a unique key.
2. You need a way to update this "SortOrder" column via the UI

**Easy to program, easy to use:** Implement a simple drag+drop interface in HTML using jQuery or whatever javascript library works for you.  In the on-complete method (or in response to a save button), trigger an ajax call which will simply send an array of `id`s in the correct order.  On the database side, loop over it and update the SortOrder accordingly, starting at 1, then 2, etc...

**Harder to program, hard to use:** Implement a classical move-up and move-down buttons. When clicked, send the `id` and `action` (eg, up, down) to the server.  There are several strategies to handle this update, but I will outline a couple:

Assuming the user clicked "move up", you can swap IDs with the previous record.

Find the previous record: `SELECT id FROM hln_stations WHERE SortOrder < (SELECT SortOrder FROM hln_stations WHERE id = ...) ORDER BY SortOrder DESC LIMIT 1`

Run two update statements, swapping the SortOrder. Reverse for moving down.  Add special code to detect top or bottom.

**etc...**

There are other ways, but for a web interface, I suggest you do Drag+Drop, as the users will love it.

Comment: Ok, just added an Int sortorder column to the database, manually typed in numbers from 0-20 for all the existing records. When I try to make that column unique, I get: **The following indexes appear to be equal and one of them should be removed: PRIMARY, id** So I would like to try to implement the "classical" approach, but not sure how to do that in PHP

Comment: @alphablender sounds like you tried to add a second primary key onto your id field...

Answer (score 3):

Databases are not "stored" in any order. They are stored in whatever way is convenient for the storage subsystem. If you delete a record, a new record may use the space of the old record "inserting" itself into the database. While it may seem like the database always returns records in a particular order, you can't rely on it.

The ONLY way to assure a sort order is to have a field to sort on.

Answer (score 3):

Dont know where you can find example to find example. but you can look the following code it is very basic:
Let `id` is your primary key and there is a column `sort_order`. You want to store primary keys in the following order: 5,4,3,6,8,7,9,10,2,1.
then you store them in an array:

```
$my_sorted = array(5,4,3,6,8,7,9,10,2,1);
```

then you update your table:

```
update `mytable` set `sort_order` = (index of $my_sorted) WHERE `id`=(array value of that index).
```

Instead of doing many queries you can do it in one query like:

```
$query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET sort_order= CASE id ";

foreach($my_sorted as $key=>$val){
  $query .= " WHEN '$val' THEN $key ";
 }
 $query .="END";
```

Then you run $query in mysql.

After updating table you can select from `mytable` with order by sort_order asc or desc.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"re-ordering" the database would require two records swapping primary keys, or most likely they would need to have all data except the primary keys be swapped. this would most likely be undesireable, since the primary key should be the one way you can consistently refer to a particular record.

The separate order field would be the way to go. Just make sure that you put an index on the order field so that things stay speedy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find out in which order databases stores data. When we query to database, we specify the field name that we want our data to be sorted by.
In your case, I would add a new column: `sequence` int(10). and write php function to change/update sequence number. when i will use select query, I will order by sequence number.

Comment: where can I find some example php functions that do this? And why does phpMyadmin complain when I try to make the new sort_order column an index? See the comment at the bottom of this page for the error message.